# How do I store the user information in python so that i can keep using it next time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, when :

```
name = input('Please enter your name:\n')
```

and input : `William`

after I close the python shell the variable "name" is gone. How can i save this information so that i can use it for next time?

Comment: you can write it to file.
`f = open('myfile','w')
f.write(name)
f.close()` then read  justit from file

Comment: Have a look at [Python's data persistence modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html).  More specifically, `pickle` and `shelve` are very easy to get started with, and `sqlite3` is quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing to files: [Python 3.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

```
filename = 'names.txt'
name = str(input('Give me your name, now!\nName: '))
with open(filename, 'w') as f: f.write(name)
with open(filename, 'r') as f: original_name = str(f.read()).strip()
```

Storing information in a SQLite3 database: [Python 3.5 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html)

```
import sqlite3
name = str(input('Give me your name, now!\nName: '))
with sqlite3.connect('names.db') as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST Name (person_name TEXT);'
        'INSERT INTO Name VALUES ({});'.format(name)
    )
    conn.commit()

    original_name = cur.execute(
        'SELECT * FROM Name'
    ).fetchall()[0]
```

Storing/serializing actual Python objects into files (with the ability to reload them): [Python 3.5 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

```
import pickle
name = str(input('Give me your name, now!\nName: '))
with open('names.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(name, f)
with open('names.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    original_name = pickle.load(f)
```